# Create an object within a velocity template

Tags: velocity

I've looked at this question already, but it's talking about liferay-velocity and seems to have access to this '$portal' object that I don't have access to.

[Create object in velocity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826547/create-object-in-velocity-template)

Specifically I'm trying to create a Locale object within the template to pass it into a $dateTool.format call to get the output in a specific language.

I can't create the locale object and pass it into the template beforehand because that code could call a variety of templates, each of which could be in different languages.

I've tried

```
#set($localeClass = $portal.getClass().forName("java.util.Locale"))
$localeClass.getName
```

but that just output '$localeClass.getName' (I wasn't sure if $portal was some magic pre-set variable or something).

I also tried

```
#set($localeClass = java.util.Locale.class)
$localeClass.getName
```

but that gave me a runtime exception when I tried to process the template.

I saw the [ClassTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ClassTool.html) present in Velocity, but that doesn't support reflexive execution of code. I guess I could try something like `$classTool.inspect("java.util.Locale").getType.getConstructor([$classTool.inspect("java.util.String"),$classTool.inspect("java.util.String")]).newInstance(["es","ES"])`.

I'll try that out, but in the meantime I'll see if anyone else has a better idea.

**EDIT**

Since posting, I realized that velocity has a ConversionTool (which wasn't listed on their GenericTool overview page), that has a toLocale function I can call. So I can use

```
$dateTool.format('dd-MMM-yyyy', $date, $conversionTool.toLocale("es_ES"))
```

But I'm still curious if there was a way to accomplish this via reflection.

Comment: I see this is old, but I'm on this for hours, I've added a new instance of ConversionTool to the Velocity context with the name conversionTool, but whenever I do a simple toLocale("en_GB") it complains about nullpointer in the format method at runtime. (on the line it uses the locale). 

Any things you had to set up? In a simple unit test it works fine. (calling toLocale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it alright but you should use `$localeClass.getName()` or `$localeClass.name` instead of `$localeClass.getName`. See the [Property Lookup Rules](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules) in the Velocity user guide.

This:

```
#set($localeClass = $portal.getClass().forName("java.util.Locale"))
$localeClass.getName()
```

correctly outputs the String "java.util.Locale" for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you may also use

```
$localeUtil.fromLanguageId("es_ES")
```

for getting locale in a Velocity template.

As for me I've also tried to use reflection for getting locale recently but didn't succeed. So I'm curious if it's ever possible too.